# Which JVM does netty Use?

Tags: java, netty

Which JVM does Netty Use?

I am new to Server Development. I am a bit concerned about paying for JVMs. Henceforth I asked this question...

Comment: Being a library, can't you use it with multiple JVMs -- or, rather, any that could run say, JBoss? (Why would it be tied to or "use" one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses ... whatever one you're using or want to use.

All JVMs have to be compliant with the JLS (Java Language Specification) or they're not really a JVM. Netty currently requires a Java <strike>1.6</strike> 1.5 (or later) JVM, however the next release is going to require 1.6 or higher.

(Edited to correct dumb user error on my part looking at the wrong branch on github)

Comment: And you don't have to pay for that.

Comment: @maerics - I checked the `.pom` for the current version before posting ... it targets 1.6

Comment: @maerics - actually ... you made me double-check. 3.2.0 requires 1.5, the next release is requiring 1.6 - I didn't change the damn branch in github when I was looking, thanks for keeping me honest :)

Comment: I suppose we have pay for the Container. I know Apache is Free for Commercial Usage.  Are there any other Containers that are free for commercial usage...

Comment: Erm ... there's only a couple that *aren't*. Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc, etc are all open source. In fact, I can't think of a servlet container that isn't free (IBM WebSphere, maybe?). You can purchase *support contracts* but they are not mandatory.